# iOS search result duplicate

Tags: ios, uitableview, search, uitextfield, nsnotifications

I have a `UItableView` that filled with songs taken from a server. I am loading songs 10 by 10 when scroll the tableview. I wanted to add a search functionality for this. So I used a `UITextField`. This is how I implemented my searching.

in my `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:srchtextbox];



-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:(NSNotification *)notification
{


[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(GetArtistSongs)
                                           object:nil];

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(SearchLocalSong)
                                           object:nil];



currentSrchStr = srchtextbox.text;
songstable.hidden=YES;
loading=YES;
songArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
datacameNull=NO;
startRec=0;

if (dm.isfromLocal) {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(SearchLocalSong) withObject:nil];
}
else
{
     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(GetArtistSongs) withObject:nil];
}



}
```

my GetArtistSongs method

```
-(void)GetArtistSongs
{
NSMutableArray *newsongarray;
if(dm.isfromLocal)
{
    newsongarray=[dbaccess GetLocalPlaylistSongs:lblArtistname.text];
    [songArray removeAllObjects];
}

else
{
    newsongarray=[ws GetPlaylistSongsByPage:selectedPlaylistID :currentSrchStr :0 :0 :0 :0 :startRec :recCount];
}



if (newsongarray!=nil) {
    [songArray addObjectsFromArray:newsongarray];

}
else
{
    songcameNull=YES;
}

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(songsLoaded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

then

```
-(void)songsLoaded{

loading=NO;
[mainactivityindicator stopAnimating];

[songstable reloadData];
songstable.hidden=NO;
songstable.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

My problem is the results getting duplicate.songs are searching correctly. But if there is a song called 'Song ABC' it duplicates several times.When I check the `SongArray` in log cat, it contains same song multiple times. What should be the reason for this. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem might be in the `else` case, where you do not flush the `songArray` contents:

```
-(void)GetArtistSongs
{
NSMutableArray *newsongarray;
if(dm.isfromLocal)
{
    newsongarray=[dbaccess GetLocalPlaylistSongs:lblArtistname.text];
    [songArray removeAllObjects];
}

else
{
    newsongarray=[ws GetPlaylistSongsByPage:selectedPlaylistID :currentSrchStr :0 :0 :0 :0 :startRec :recCount];

    [songArray removeAllObjects];  // <---------- Here
}
```